# Only load current page, when swiped to - Using android pageviewer

Tags: java, android, rss

I am currently creating an RSS feed reading app, using the page viewer control which comes with android. I have four pages which are loaded using fragments, the problem is, is that when swiping between each page...often the app freezes for a couple of seconds, before actually swiping to the next fragment.

The reason for this, I have found, is that the page viewer is not only loading the current fragment it is on; but also the next fragment along the list; and given that each of the fragments has the potential to have 50+ items in a listView, which is being populated by a data connection to an RSS feed, it means that it is trying to load two listViews at once with large ammounts of data. Therefore, making the app freeze.

My question is, given my code below, how would I make this run smoother. Is there a way of only loading the current fragment you are on, and not the next one as well, and then when you swipe to the next fragment...the new one loads etc?

Any suggestions will be helpful, and I can paste more code if anyone wishes.

Thanks!

The code which adds the fragments to the pageViewer:

```
    package com.example.directrssread;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class ViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    //boolean addFirstPage = true;

       /** maintains the pager adapter*/
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
        //initialsie the pager



        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the fragments to be paged
     */



    private void initialisePaging() {

        boolean addFirstPage = ((GlobalVariables) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();

         final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();// getActionBar();
         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
         final ViewPager mViewPager;
         mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

         // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {



                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                  public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                        // When the tab is selected, switch to the
                        // corresponding page in the ViewPager.
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                //int curr = mViewPager.get
                String currTab = "";
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    currTab = "EPL";
                }

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    currTab = "Champ";
                }

                if (i == 2)
                {
                    currTab = "League One";
                }

                if (i == 3)
                {
                    currTab = "League Two";
                }
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()

                                .setText(currTab)
                                .setTabListener(tabListener));

            }

            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                    new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            // When swiping between pages, select the
                            // corresponding tab.
                            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                        }
                    });


        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed1.class.getName()));       

               fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed3.class.getName()));

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed4.class.getName()));

       // fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter1(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        //
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    }

}
```

One of my listView pages:

```
   package com.example.directrssread;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Feed1 extends ListFragment{

    String[] URL = new String[3];
    int count = 0;
    String currURL = "";
    View mView;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //Map<Date, ArrayList> menuItems = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>();
    Map<Date, ArrayList> sortedMap = null;
    //ProgressDialog.Builder builder;
    // final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog((ViewPagerFragmentActivity)getActivity());
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
    static final String KEY_PUBTIME = "pubDate";


     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         Log.e("Feed1", "Feed1");

         mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed1, container, false);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed1, container, false);

        }

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         menuItems.removeAll(menuItems);
         count = 0;     
          rssRun(); 
          Log.e("Count", String.valueOf(menuItems.size()));     
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         }

     public void rssRun()
     {

         Log.e("FEED1", "Running feed1");
         boolean runSubstring = true;
            //URL[0] = "http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/a/arsenal/rss.xml";
            URL[0] = "http://www.football365.com/premier-league/rss";
            URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            //URL[2] = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";

            //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            for (int f= 0;f < URL.length;f++)
            {

            try{
                 //Log.e("TEst1", "TEst");

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            Log.e("HERE", "HERE");
            //Log.e("XML", xml);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
            // looping through all item nodes <item>

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                if (doc!=null)
                {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    currURL = "Football365";
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    currURL = "BBC Sport";
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    //currURL = "SkySports";
                }

                //map.remove(map);

                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                //Get the title of the article.
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                //Get the description of the article.
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                //Get the source e.g ' Football365'.
                //String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                //Parse the date and time from the main strings.
                //Chop off the un-wanted parts.
                //Bring them back together in one string.
                String pubTime = pubDate.substring(17, pubDate.length());
                String pubDateFormat = "";
                pubTime = pubTime.substring(0, 5);
                map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, pubTime);  

                pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 22);
                pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, 16);

                pubDate = pubDate + " " + pubTime;


                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
                Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
                dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                //Log.e("DATE", dateFormatter.format(date));
                //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                //String currDate
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String currDate = sdf.format(new Date());
                //Log.e("CURRENT DATE", currDate);
                //System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
                //System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));

                //Log.e("TITLE", )      
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, currURL + " - " + pubDate);          
                //Add the link.
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                //Get the publish date.
                //map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                //10
                //if (dateFormatter.format(date) == currDate)
//              if (dateFormatter.format(date).substring(0, 10) == currDate.substring(0, 10))
                //String  input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
                //input = input.replace(" ", "");
                currDate = currDate.replace(" ", "");
                String rssDate = dateFormatter.format(date).replace(" ", "");
                Date dt1 = dateFormatter.parse(currDate);
                Date dt2 = dateFormatter.parse(rssDate);
                //Log.e("TRIM CURR", currDate);
                //Log.e("RSSDATE", rssDate);
                //if (rssDate == currDate)
                if (dt1.compareTo(dt2)==0)//== currDate)
                {
                    menuItems.add(map);
                    Collections.sort(menuItems, new MapComparator(KEY_PUBTIME));
                    Collections.reverse(menuItems);
                    //sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>(menuItems);
                    //Log.e("SAME", "THE SAME");
                }
                //Log.e("TRIM CURR1", currDate);
                //Log.e("RSSDATE1", rssDate);
                //Log.e("TEst", "TEst");
                for (int q = 0;q < map.size();q++)
                {
                    //Log.e("mene", map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                }


                }

            }
            count+=1;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            }

            // Adding menuItems to ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
            //if (count==3)
            //{

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            //}

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            //TextView txt = getTextView();

            //TextView firstName = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//          TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            //ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l)
            //ListView lv = ((ListView) findViewbyId(R.id)

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
        }


        // mDialog.dismiss();
         Log.e("RUN", "RSSRUN");
     }

     class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
           // private Main longOperationContext = null;

           // public LongOperation(Main context) {

           // }


            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                Log.e("FEED1", "Running feed1");
                 boolean runSubstring = true;
                    //URL[0] = "http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/a/arsenal/rss.xml";
                    URL[0] = "http://www.football365.com/premier-league/rss";
                    URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
                    //URL[2] = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";

                    //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
                    for (int f= 0;f < URL.length;f++)
                    {

                    try{
                         //Log.e("TEst1", "TEst");

                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
                    Log.e("HERE", "HERE");
                    //Log.e("XML", xml);

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
                    // looping through all item nodes <item>

                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        if (doc!=null)
                        {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            currURL = "Football365";
                        }
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            currURL = "BBC Sport";
                        }
                        if (count == 2)
                        {
                            //currURL = "SkySports";
                        }

                        //map.remove(map);

                        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                        //Get the title of the article.
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                        //Get the description of the article.
                        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                        //Get the source e.g ' Football365'.
                        //String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                        String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                        //Parse the date and time from the main strings.
                        //Chop off the un-wanted parts.
                        //Bring them back together in one string.
                        String pubTime = pubDate.substring(17, pubDate.length());
                        String pubDateFormat = "";
                        pubTime = pubTime.substring(0, 5);
                        map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, pubTime);  

                        pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 22);
                        pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, 16);

                        pubDate = pubDate + " " + pubTime;


                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
                        Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
                        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        //Log.e("DATE", dateFormatter.format(date));
                        //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                        //String currDate
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        String currDate = sdf.format(new Date());
                        //Log.e("CURRENT DATE", currDate);
                        //System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
                        //System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));

                        //Log.e("TITLE", )      
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, currURL + " - " + pubDate);          
                        //Add the link.
                        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                        //Get the publish date.
                        //map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        //10
                        //if (dateFormatter.format(date) == currDate)
//                      if (dateFormatter.format(date).substring(0, 10) == currDate.substring(0, 10))
                        //String  input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
                        //input = input.replace(" ", "");
                        currDate = currDate.replace(" ", "");
                        String rssDate = dateFormatter.format(date).replace(" ", "");
                        Date dt1 = dateFormatter.parse(currDate);
                        Date dt2 = dateFormatter.parse(rssDate);
                        //Log.e("TRIM CURR", currDate);
                        //Log.e("RSSDATE", rssDate);
                        //if (rssDate == currDate)
                        if (dt1.compareTo(dt2)==0)//== currDate)
                        {
                            menuItems.add(map);
                            Collections.sort(menuItems, new MapComparator(KEY_PUBTIME));
                            Collections.reverse(menuItems);
                            //sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>(menuItems);
                            //Log.e("SAME", "THE SAME");
                        }
                        //Log.e("TRIM CURR1", currDate);
                        //Log.e("RSSDATE1", rssDate);
                        //Log.e("TEst", "TEst");
                        for (int q = 0;q < map.size();q++)
                        {
                            //Log.e("mene", map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                        }


                        }

                    }
                    count+=1;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
                    }

                    // Adding menuItems to ListView
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                            R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
                    //if (count==3)
                    //{

                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                        //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    //}

                    // selecting single ListView item
                    ListView lv = getListView();

                    //TextView txt = getTextView();

                    //TextView firstName = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//                  TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    //ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l)
                    //ListView lv = ((ListView) findViewbyId(R.id)

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem
                            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
                            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                            // Starting new intent
                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                            startActivity(in);

                        }
                    });
                }
                return currURL;

            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            }
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }


            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            }    

        }


     class MapComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>>
     {
         private final String key;

         public MapComparator(String key)
         {
             this.key = key;
         }

         public int compare(Map<String, String> first,
                            Map<String, String> second)
         {
             // TODO: Null checking, both for maps and values
             String firstValue = first.get(key);
             String secondValue = second.get(key);
             return ((String) first.get(key)).compareTo((String) second.get(key));
            // return firstValue.compareTo(secondValue);
         }
     }


}
```

Comment: i think u need androd viewpager with action bar

Comment: Have a look http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: Yes I have the action bar added to the class (the tab view one)

Comment: Do you populate the `ListView` asynchronously?

Comment: Hmm, no I do not think so. I shall paste one of my listView pages in the question.

Comment: Ok, I have pasted my listView code into the question.

Comment: Thanks. Well here's the good thing: You've got an `AsyncTask`. The bad: You never call it and furthermore setting the `ListAdaper` and `onItemClickListener` isn't the way to go. And what's your `ThreadPolicy` stuff for?

Comment: The threadpolicy stuff was because I am trying to access network operations from the main thread, so I found that and it fixed it. So you would recommend using this async task then?

Comment: Definitely. Network Operations should always run in an AsyncTask. There's really no need to change the ThreadPolicy on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments: I'd recommend you to use an AsyncTask in order to load the content. Following what you need to change. (Just a raw overview)

Here's how your **AsyncTask** should basically look like:

```
class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int f= 0;f < params.length;f++)
        {

            try{
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(params[f]); // getting XML
                // Parse xml, add to your Map etc.
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               // Handle exception
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        setupListView();
    }
}
```

**Please note:** *I've changed the Parameters of the AsyncTask. Furthermore the URL's are accessed via the params, not via the array that you've defined gloabally.*

In `setupListView`, which shouldn't be part of the AsyncTask, you create and set the adapter as well as the `onItemClickListener`. Don't do this in the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask`.

```
private void setupListView(){
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                // ...
            };
}
```

In order to run the AsyncTask you simply call the following line, including all of the URL's that you wan't to load:

```
  new LongOperation().execute(
            "http://www.football365.com/premier-league/rss",
            "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk",
            "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml");
```

And to answer you question: *"Is there a way to prevent the loading of the next `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`?"* - No, at least as far as I know. That's because the next Fragment needs to be loaded prior to the swipe-gesture. (Otherwise nothing would be visible)